# Module can't export existing name

Tags: rebol

I wish to redefine `print` in a module and to export it --- just noticed I can't: only non-existing names can be exported.
Any workaround?

Comment: Strangely enough,  one can redefine lib/print in module, and the change stay visible in user context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/concepts/modules-loading.html under the heading: Explicit references into modules.

Loading a module will currently never redefine a word in the user context.
I can't tell if this is a design decision or because modules are not fully baked yet.

Fortunately, there is a terrible work-around: DIY.

In your case to redefine 'print to be the 'print from your-module execute the following Rebol code:

```
your-module: import %your-module-filename print: :your-module/print
```

Also, don't try unsetting 'print before loading your module, I tried and that doesn't work either, so, a topic for another SO question.

Comment: Good. And one can also define an `export` function in module and call it in main code to do the work. [But see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284088/trouble-with-export-word-in-module]