# Trouble with 'export word in module

Tags: rebol, rebol3

Let's mod.reb:

```
    REBOL[Type: module Name: mod]
    export: add 1 2
```

Let's test.reb:

```
    import 'mod
```

Running `r3 test.reb`,
got:

```
    ** Script error: add has no value
    ** Where: do module catch case load-module apply for-each case import do either either either --anonymous--
    ** Near: ... add 3 2
```

Same trouble with other funcs instead of 'add.

No trouble with other names instead of 'export

No trouble inserting a dummy `'export` before `export: ...` (!?)

Why this?

Comment: Looks to be a bug in the way modules collects words for export which in turn is due to a bug in PARSE. In Rebol 2, `parse [foo:][to 'foo skip]` would return FALSE, however in Rebol 3 this returns TRUE, even if `parse [foo:][to 'foo 'foo]` returns FALSE.